# Trouble with UITableViewCellAccessory (Checkmark/None toggle)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

`edit`
Well now don't I feel like an idiot. Until now, I haven't been paying any attention to whether or not a cell gets a checkmark. Somehow, I had `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` flipped, so it was turning off when I wanted it on and turning on when I wanted it off. Reading code properly really does help with debugging...
`/edit`

Below is the code I was having so much trouble with.
From `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (i.need == 0) { // item not needed - hide (#) and turn on checkmark
    i.need = 1;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", i.name];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else if (i.need < 0) { // item not needed - hide (#) and turn on checkmark
    i.need = -i.need;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", i.name];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else { // item not needed - show (#) and turn off checkmark
    i.need = -i.need;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)", i.name, -i.need];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

The following is what you get for making this mistake.

```
Tap row with checkmark: (#) hidden, checkmark removed
Tap row without checkmark: (#) shown, checkmark not set until next tap
```

Comment: I'd go ahead and delete this, but I figure it couldn't hurt to leave it up and possibly help someone else. Moderator-person, feel free to kill it anyway if you disagree.

Comment: Right, right. I guess that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how I made the mistake of not connecting comment and accessory, but there you go. This is what it *should* look like:

```
if (i.need == 0) { // item not needed - hide (#) and turn on checkmark
    i.need = 1;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", i.name];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else if (i.need < 0) { // item not needed - hide (#) and turn on checkmark
    i.need = -i.need;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", i.name];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else { // item not needed - show (#) and turn off checkmark
    i.need = -i.need;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)",
                                                            i.name, -i.need];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```